# ul 100% of its parent

Tags: html, css

I want my list width to be `100%` of his parent width. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <ul class="tab" >

        <li class="tab1">
            <a > Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab12">
            <a > Overview2</a>
        </li>
     </ul></div>
```

CSS:

```
body>#page {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}
```

I tried with `width: 100%;` on ul element but it doesnt work. How can i do it?

Comment: have you tried `width:inherit;` ?

Comment: I just fiddled it. It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/WuVrB/2/ Yellow is UL

Comment: It seems to be working for me with `width: 100%`: http://jsfiddle.net/uLyrF/ Notice that the `div` is purple and `ul` is blue.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 your ul is bigger than the parent, scroll to the right.

Comment: @GregoireD. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/uLyrF/3/ Also note that you can get rid of the default `padding` on the `ul` element instead of applying `box-sizing`. Either way works.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Wow, cool think about the `box-sizing`. I'm always bitched by the padding while doing 100% width things, and try to handle them with negative margin.

Comment: I did it. Thnx to all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: the ul's width is 100%, the div's width some 980 pixels.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="demo">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#demo {
    width:980px;
}

div#demo ul {
    width:100%;
}

div#demo li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:33%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EU65T/

Answer (score 0):

```
#page ul li {
width: 100%;
}
```

This will make the list element `100% width` of the `ul` parent. Also the ul is 100%;

Answer (score 0):

The list width itself should already be 100% wide. `<li>`, `<ul>` and `<div>` are all block-level elements already and should *by default* take up 100% of the width.

But `<a>` is an *inline*-level element by default, so `width` will not apply. You need to make it a *block*-level element with `display:inline-block;` and `width:100%` to have the width be `100%` of it's parent's width.

I suspect that you also want to be giving the `<li>` a width and making them `display:inline-block` so that they sit next to each other on the same line.